# How to scroll horizontally with an external compatible mouse that has no wheel button ability?

Tags: mouse, macos

I bought a new external compatible mouse for my MacBook, the [ECHTPower F-35](https://echtpower.com/products/ECHTPower-Vertical-Mouse).

Sometime, I need to scroll horizontally, but the wheel button doesn't work.

So, as an Apple newbie user, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: This site doesn't work so well for [basic customer support questions](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y?rq=1). Have you reached out to the vendor already (they claim Mac compatibility on their site)?

Comment: @nohillside my question was generic, not related to my mouse model. I thought there was a workaround like a shortcut as keyboard button + left mouse click or something similar.

Comment: Normally, you hold shift while scrolling, but what do you mean by “Wheel Button?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am **not** sure about the **mouse** but there is a shortcut with the **keyboard**.

For scrolling left: <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd>

For scrolling right:  <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>